# ProgressSpinner not visible in progress dialog/progressbar

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I am using [this samsung Iris device](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-iris-3518) for my development.

I have shown a `progressdialog` and `progressbar` as and where required.

This is the code for `progressdialog` :

```
    ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressBar.setMessage("Please Wait");
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.show();
```

And this is for progressbar :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But it shows like this :

[image]

No `progressSpinner` is seen and this issue happens only in this tablet. If i run on any other device, then it works fine. Cannot use any other device as it is a business requirement.

Comment: what is the theme of that activity it may because of theme

Comment: if a user has transitions turned off in developer options, your animations in a ProgressDialog (namely the Progress Spinner) will not show. Turn them on and restart the app and you will see the spinner!

Comment: It takes colorAccent color for spinner color. check that color is not white.

Comment: this is the theme of the activity :  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#da1f16</item>
    </style>

Comment: @ABDevelopers Thank you. worked like a charm.

Comment: I have added it as an answer . Accept it for other people to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user has transitions turned off in developer options, your animations in a `ProgressDialog` (namely the Progress `Spinner`) will not show. Turn them on and restart the app and you will see the spinner!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
ProgressDialog progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

**In style :**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```